# Shall I use the term 'Gallery' or 'Library' for a collection of items?

Tags: lists, terminology, language

I have a collection of items that a user can choose from. I need to give this collection a name but I am unsure as to what. I don't want to use the collection name 'Saved Items' as this will confuse the user due to the fact it can contain items from various sources, not just items they have saved.

Therefore a collection name such as 'Gallery' or 'Library' would make sense to use.

**Which term is best?**

**Further info on the types of items:** - each one has a name, description and associated settings. I can't say much else, it's a secret.

Comment: What sort of 'items' are they? Photographs? E-commerce products? Pdf books?

Comment: @JonW the information you are after has been added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it depends on a particular situation, I would do it like this:

If the items are final (something user posts and it is an entity which is not reused furthermore except displaying) - I would use **Gallery** term.

If the collection consists of both user-submitted items and predefined items and user can use them furthermore, I would use **Library** term.

The reason is that *gallery* originates in a name of a place where you can just view some works (e.g. paintings) while *library* term originates in a name of a place where you can grab items (books) for further usage (you *take* them home to read and "transform" into own resource, which is knowledge.

Comment: good way to justify usage of each term. Library sounds like the more relevant name to use in my case based on your definitions

Comment: Well, these are not 'definitions' rather general feeling about the meaning of these terms. For sure you can do more with items from library than from gallery (you cannot even touch the paintings ;)).

Comment: unless your name's Banksy